# Set shipping price according to product category

Tags: magento, configuration, categories

Need to set up different shipping prices according to categories.

Like if I have 2 categories say a and b in admin.

I need to set up a $10 shipping for the product from category A and $15 for the product from category b

I was checking in the cart rules but can't find anything there.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this link.Hope its help you

http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/change-shipping-price-handling-fee-fly-magento/

Answer (score 0):

```
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/310755/
```

please use this, create one custom modules then you will be see in admin categories one text field in "General Tab", Add your shipping price and get on checkout page using that code.

```
<?php echo  Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/fieldName'); ?>
```

And create your condition.